# EXCEL: Count of Column Items For Every Distinct Item In Another

Tags: excel

In my Excel sheet, I have 2 columns. Names of restaurants, and ratings for each one. For each rating, a new row is created, so of course a restaurant name occurs multiple times.

```
Restaurant   Rating
McDonalds    8
McDonalds    7
Red Robin    5
Qdoba        7
```

Etc.

How can I get the number of times each rating happens for each restaurant? We'll say rating goes from 1-10.

I want it to look like this:

```
Restaurant   1(rating)   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
McDonalds    889         22  45  77  484 443 283 333 44  339
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's called `COUNTIFS`

Comment: @Jeeped That works to showing how many times each rating occurs for every distinct restaurant?

Comment: Anyone got a link to a good question or answer today? There have been so many pathetic questions that my upvote/downvote ratio is leaning the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pivot Tables:
Use a pivot tables to set your rows at "Restaurant" and your columns as "Rating" and your values as "Count of Rating"

Using Countifs:
[image: Using Countifs]

Comment: And I guess the one question I now have is how to add another field to the pivot table, since it won't let me create one with both columns highlighted. @Jeeped, I'm sorry for my pathetic question, I only started working on Excel last week :/

Comment: I dont understand this second question.  Is there more to your original problem than just counting?  Pivottables are not always the best solution and it would help you to look into how to use the countifs function and create your own table from there.  You can recreate the pivottable I described above using just countifs.  Good learning exercise for you.

Comment: Whenever I create the table, I can only select Restaurant, or only select Rating. Only one of them appear on the field name list. I need to add both.

Comment: Drag Restaurant into the "Row" box in the pivot table editor on the right.  Then drag Rating into the column box.  Then drag Rating into the Value box.

Comment: And if I did countif, what I find difficult is that I have about 3000 different restaurants, and 10 different ratings. I'd have to use some sort of loop through VBA, and nested CountIf statement. Because I want the count of every rating for every restaurant.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You have the list of restaurants in column A and the rating across the top in Row 1.  You just use references to count how many 1's are in McDonald's.  I'll edit my post to show you countifs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154717/discussion-between-tim-and-andrew-wolfe).